# FAQ Troubleshooter creation software

Tags: open-source, workflow

I am looking for software similar to Microsoft's troubleshooter. It can be a web application, a desktop application, it doesn't really matter.

Required features:
    - Design workflows that branch out based on user input
    - Present the designed workflows to a user as an application
    - Be able to send the followed workflows to an e-mail so they can be reviewed

Is there any such software?

Comment: The magic word is "wizard"; try using that in your Google searches. If you can program, reaad  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k3w6w59.aspx

Comment: @Mawg Thank you, I found that very helpful. While I can programm, we're looking for a solution our HR can potentially use as well.

Comment: Them I guess that either you code it for them :-) or you find a Wizard Builder. The tricky bit will be sending the email at the end. I am sorry that I don't know of any free wizard builder :-(